# Unlocks app even after payment decline

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I develop an app with in app version 2 and publish it on developers Google now some one download the app and try to purchase it. On purchasing a message showed to him that "Your card is decline" now even after this message app got "unlock" . Now this is a very difficult situation that payment is not made while app got unlock. Is this issue with in app billing method(logic) in my app or its with Google.

If its in my app then is there any method which check that the person card is a "declined card" so in this method i can restrict my app not to unlock the app.

Any app will be appreciated.

I have this code in my BillingReceviver:

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (Consts.ACTION_PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            String signedData = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNED_DATA);
            String signature = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.INAPP_SIGNATURE);
            purchaseStateChanged(context, signedData, signature);
        } else if (Consts.ACTION_NOTIFY.equals(action)) {
            String notifyId = intent.getStringExtra(Consts.NOTIFICATION_ID);
            if (Consts.DEBUG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "notifyId: " + notifyId);
            }
            notify(context, notifyId);
        } else if (Consts.ACTION_RESPONSE_CODE.equals(action)) {
            long requestId = intent.getLongExtra(Consts.INAPP_REQUEST_ID, -1);
            int responseCodeIndex = intent.getIntExtra(Consts.INAPP_RESPONSE_CODE,
                    ResponseCode.RESULT_ERROR.ordinal());
            checkResponseCode(context, requestId, responseCodeIndex);
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "unexpected action: " + action);
        }
    }
```

After making ACTION_PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED matches the action the my purchsedstatechanged calls in file BillingService

```
  private void purchaseStateChanged(int startId, String signedData, String signature) {
        ArrayList<Security.VerifiedPurchase> purchases;
        DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(this);
        purchases = Security.verifyPurchase(signedData, signature);
       if (purchases == null) {
            return;
        }

        ArrayList<String> notifyList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (VerifiedPurchase vp : purchases) {
            if (vp.notificationId != null) {
                notifyList.add(vp.notificationId);
            }


            ResponseHandler.purchaseResponse(this, vp.purchaseState, vp.productId,
                    vp.orderId, vp.purchaseTime, vp.developerPayload);



        db.addUser("com.example.app", "111", "1222");

        Log.i("Usgdgfer",""+db.isUserPresent("com.example.app"));
        }
        if (!notifyList.isEmpty()) {
            String[] notifyIds = notifyList.toArray(new String[notifyList.size()]);
            confirmNotifications(startId, notifyIds);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please if any one know about that then provide some info

Comment: Can you elaborate on the answer to this problem.  I still don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the card has to be mapped to the Google Wallet account before the purchase is made. If the card is invalid, it will show an error while you map the card to your Google account.

Seems strange that the card is being validated during purchase. Even then, if the payment is not made properly , you should get an error response

> BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_USER_CANCELED = 1;
>   BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE = 3;

Check if you handle these errors properly after you receive them in the IabResult. Make sure you unlock your app only when you receive a proper response.

Comment: either way, be sure to make the app conversion decisions based on response code received (ERROR, CANCELED, OK et al). As far as the implementation is concerned, using v3 is much easier.